# How to await/subscribe to internal variables updating from null?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using SpeechRecognition in the browser and I've created a speech service:

```
this.recognition.addEventListener('result', (e) => {
    if (e.results) {
        let result = e.results[e.resultIndex];
        console.log('Final? ' + result.isFinal);
        let _transcript = result[0].transcript;
        let _confidence = result[0].confidence;
        if (result.isFinal) {
            console.log('Final result: ' + _transcript);
            this.finalText = _transcript; // <---------------- FinalText updated
        } else {
            console.log('Confidence? ' + _confidence);
            if (_confidence > 0.6) {
                this.finalText = _transcript;  // <---------------- FinalText updated
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Inside my service I have a `start()` function that returns a promise with the `finalText string` but my current method of checking if `finalText` was updated is just not right.

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        // Keep checking for final text to update
        if (this.finalText != null) {
            console.log('Final text submitting response');
            this.finalText = null;
            return resolve('Success');
        } else {
            console.log('waiting');
            if (this.isStoppedSpeech) { // True if we clicked stop() or if the 'end' event listener fires
                return reject('Timeout');
            }
        }
        await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 500)); // sleep
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error); // Timeout
    this.stop();
});
```

All I want to do is return when `this.FinalText` has text. I was thinking perhaps I should subscribe to it somehow and then `await this.FinalText`. I just need the promise to work properly.

Example usage:

```
this.speech.start().then((s) => {
    console.log('Done speaking');
    if (this.speech.getLastPhrase() != null)
        this.pushChat({
            speak: this.speech.getLastPhrase()
        });
});
```

I do not want to use `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. How can I await for `this.FinalText` then return the value inside of my `start() function promise`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good use case for an RXJS `subject`. It is an observable from which you can emit values on demand.

Instantiate final text as a `Subject` and call `.next()` when you want to emit a value.

```js
finalText = new Subject<string>();
```

```js
    this.recognition.addEventListener('result', (e: any) => {
      if (e.results) {
        let result = e.results[e.resultIndex];
        console.log('Final? ' + result.isFinal);
        let _transcript = result[0].transcript;
        let _confidence = result[0].confidence;
        if (result.isFinal) {
          console.log('Final result: ' + _transcript);
          this.finalText.next(_transcript); // <---------------- FinalText updated
        } else {
          console.log('Confidence? ' + _confidence);
          if (_confidence > 0.6) {
            this.finalText.next(_transcript); // <---------------- FinalText updated
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

You can subscribe to the `Subject` to execute code on each `.next()` call:

```js
    this.finalText.subscribe((text) => {
      console.log('Done speaking');
      if (text)
        this.pushChat({
          speak: text,
        });
    });
```

you can also use Angular's `async` pipe to update the value in html automatically.

```html
<p>{{ finalText | async }}</p>
```

You should definitely look into the rxjs library / observables. You basically made a primitive version of an observable with your `start()` function.